Verify that the trivial group is a group
I'm studying group theory, and as an exercise, I'd like to pose to myself that a group with one element is indeed a group.
But logic-wise, this is confusing to me. How and why can I prove a group with one element is indeed a group? What is the outline? Can I just...assume all axioms are upheld? I don't completely understand.
My approach so far has been: assume the axioms are upheld, then paradoxically, verify they are upheld, but this seems circular! What do I do?

You don't need to "assume" the group laws, hold you can test them.  With only one element, this is pretty straight forward.

Sorry, but it really isn't straightforward to me, this is abstract thinking and it takes time to get accustomed to. What I'm asking for is the logical foundation. How do I know I can test "multiplication"? How do I know I can test for inverses? All these laws of logical are missing pieces that others take for granted. What am I allowed to start off assuming, and how do you know with 100% certainty you're allowed to do so?

Say your one element group is ${0}$, with operation $+$. As an example, you can show $0$ is an identity by showing $0 + a = a + 0 = a$ for all $a \in {0}$. You can verify that $0 + 0 = 0 + 0 = 0$, by definition of $+$, which proves $0 + a = a + 0 = a$ for all $a \in {0}$ by exhaustion. Show associativity by exhaustion too. For inverses, run through all the elements of ${0}$ and see if you can find a formula for the inverse of each element of ${0}$.

Okay, so one thing I'm allowed to assume in this proof is a law of composition, either "addition" or "multiplication." Do I additionally assume closure, or do I prove closure? I guess you answered that. How do you know you're allowed to assume that the law of composition exists, if what you're trying to prove is that the set is a group? I'm just confused.

Well, you need to say what the multiplication table is, though in this case the only option is $e\cdot e=e$, where $e$ is the only element. It's associative since any product, in any order, must give $e$.  There's an identity element, namely $e$, and $e$ is its own inverse.

Okay, so I'm still a little confused, but maybe it's becoming a little more clear. You and Theo both seem to stipulate that I can assume a multiplication rule exists on the set. But, do I assume closure? Or am I supposed to leverage the fact that there's only one element to prove closure?

To be clear:  it doesn't really make sense to ask whether some set is a group or not.  You need to specify the product (some binary map on the set) and then you can ask whether the set is a group with that multiplication.  Again, with just one element, there's really no choice as to what the product is.

Hmm, I guess this might be an issue that the author of the book I'm studying took for granted then, maybe I need a more clear and detail-oriented approach. Do you have recommendations for beginners?

Again, you aren't assuming the product rule exists, you have to declare how you are "multiplying" two elements and then confirm that this rule satisfies the axioms.

@QuestionsA As lulu says, you'll need to define your operation on your set ${0}$. There's only one way to do it with closure, and many ways to do it without closure (e.g. we could define $0 + 0 = \pmatrix{1 & 1 \ 2 & 1}$, which obviously prevents $({0}, +)$ from being a group). The question will be assuming that the operation has closure, otherwise it would be ridiculous.

I always liked herstein but I have no idea why they are charging so much for a paperback.

@lulu: that is ludicrous. You can get used copies from reputable sellers for reasonable prices.  I learned from Herstein myself, but I do have to say that in retrospect I find the lack of group actions to be a problem.

@lulu: why they are charging so much for a paperback --- If it's of any interest, I paid $16.60 for my (at the time, new) hardback copy (very nice, with sewn in signatures, not the glued-together format that many hardback books in recent years have been using, such as Springer's math texts) of the 1975 2nd edition in August 1976 (purchased at a university bookstore), which according to the CPI Inflation Calculator is equivalent to $91.04 at this time.

@ArturoMagidin  It's bizarre, right?  I agree re actions.

@DaveL.Renfro  Ah, you made me go check my copy.  $$15.95$, purchased in $1976$.  Still in good shape!

Afraid I can't compare; my copy is the Spanish edition from Editorial Trillas, bought in the late 80s, and the price sticker would have been in a plastic wrap which has long gone to a landfill.

@lulu: $15.95 with 4% tax rate is $16.588, so maybe the price I wrote down on the inside front cover (a practice I did with textbooks I purchased roughly during 1976-1977 and later stopped doing) was the after-tax price, as 4% seems vaguely familiar (sales tax in Charlotte, North Carolina in 1976?). Moreover, and this seems a lot more significant for the price I gave as being the after-tax price amount, a price of $15.95 sounds a lot more realistic for a pre-tax (i.e. sticker) price than $16.60!

A group is usually defined to be an ordered pair, $(G,\cdot)$, where $G$ is a set, and $\cdot$ is a binary operation on $G$ (that is, a function $G\times G\to G$) that satisfies certain conditions (associativity, has an identity, every element has an inverse).${}^1$
To describe a group $G$, generally you need to specify two things:

The underlying set of $G$; and

The binary operation $\cdot$.


Then either the fact that $(G,\cdot)$ is a group will be verified, or known.
Sometimes, $\cdot$ is either clear from context (like if I said, "the group of integers", where the only reasonable operation is usual addition); and sometimes there is really no choice of what $\cdot$ can be. For example, if the set $G$ has just one element, $G=\{\star\}$, then the only function $G\times G\to G$ is the function $\star\cdot\star = \star$. So there is no need to specify what $\cdot$: there is only one thing it could possibly be.
So here what is happening is that we are specifying the set $G$ ("the one element" set); we are eliding the operation $\cdot$ because there is only one possibility. And now we want to verify that $(\{\star\},\cdot)$ does indeed satisfy the required conditions. Once we do, we will have verified that this is indeed a group.
We get sloppy, though, and say "verify that the 1-element group is indeed a group", when we should really say

Verify that the 1-element set with the only possible binary operation defined on it is a group.

Which is how you can phrase the question so that it does not appear to assume that something you do not yet know to be a group is a group.
${}^1$ Sometimes you actually want to think of a group is consisting of a set and three operations; a binary operation $\cdot\colon G\times G\to G$ which is "multiplication", a unary operation ${}^{-1}\colon G\to G$ which is "inverse", and a nullary operation $e\colon G^0\to G$ which identifies the identity element. Then the ordered $4$-tuple $(G,\cdot,{}^{-1},e)$ is a group if and only if for all $x,y,z\in G$, $(x\cdot y)\cdot z=x\cdot(y\cdot z)$, $x\cdot e = x$, and $x\cdot x^{-1}=e$ (with $\cdot$ using infix notation, and ${}^{-1}$ using suffix notation). Here, again, with $G=\{\star\}$ there is only one possibility for ${}^{-1}$, namely $\star^{-1}=\star$, and one possibility for $e$, namely $\star$, and you then verify this does indeed satisfy these conditions.

Thank you for your detailed explanation, I'll try again to go through studying this.

"a group with one element" is a group by assumption, so there is nothing to prove. If you meant "a set with one element",  say $S=\{u\}$, then the only sensible binary operation on $S$, say $\star$, is necessarily (closure) and completely defined by:
$$u\star u=u \tag1$$
Now go through the three group axioms by taking as arbitrary elements of $G$ ("for every...") necessarily invariably $u$. By $(1)$, you'll succeed in all the three points.
